# What to return when range HTTP header requests last byte of file?

Tags: http, range

I need to handle the Range header programatically in Java for supporting media files on iOS.

If my file is 23843 bytes, for example, I'm getting a request with a range header:

```
Range: bytes 23842-23842
```

What am I meant to return in this case? Is it just the last byte of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the file from offset 23842 to offset 23842, so yes, that comes out as one byte.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1) actually gives a similar example:

> - The first and last bytes only (bytes 0 and 9999):  bytes=0-0,-1

(The important bit here being that `0-0 = first byte`)

Comment: Interestingly, iOS makes a request for 0-1 as the first request which is also the first bit. That's what threw me off.

Comment: `0-1` are the first two bytes.